# How to link two if statements

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, if-statement

I am learning JS and have created a carousel with a caption underneath.

**How do I get the Prev/Next buttons to affect the caption as well as the image**? I've tried combining the if statements in several ways but have failed miserably.

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<span id="prev" class="arrow">&#10094;</span>
<div class="karussell" id="karussell">
    <a href="#"><img class="karu" name="esislaid"></a>
</div>
<span id="next" class="arrow">&#10095;</span>
<div class="caption">
    <h3 id="esikiri"></h3>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var p = 0;
var s = 0;
    var esileht = [];
    var aeg = 5000;
    var kiri = [];

    //Image List
    esileht[0] = 'img/tooted/raamat/graafvanalinn2016.jpg';
    esileht[1] = 'img/tooted/kaart/kaart_taskus_esipool.jpg';
    esileht[2] = 'img/tooted/kaart/graafkaart_esikylg.jpg';

    //Captions
    kiri[0] = 'Raamat &quot;Tallinn. Graafiline vanalinn&quot;';
    kiri[1] = 'Tallinna vanalinna graafiline kaart (suur formaat)';
    kiri[2] = 'Tallinna vanalinna graafiline kaart (v&auml;ike formaat)';


// Left and Right arrows


    //Eelmine
    function eelmine(){
        if (p === 0){
            p = esileht.length;
        }
        p = p - 1;
        return esileht[p];

    }
    //Jargmine
    function jargmine(){
        p = p + 1;
        p = p % esileht.length;
        return esileht[p];


    }


document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = eelmine();
}
);

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = jargmine();
}
);
    //Change Image

    function changePilt (){
        document.esislaid.src = esileht[p];

        if(p < esileht.length -1){
        p++;
        } else {
        p = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("changePilt()", aeg);
    }

    //Change Caption

    function changeKiri(){
    document.getElementById('esikiri').innerHTML = kiri[s];

    if(s < kiri.length - 1){
        s++;
        }
        else {
            s = 0;
        }
        setTimeout('changeKiri()', aeg);
    }

document.body.onload = function(){
    changePilt();
    changeKiri();
};
```

**CSS, just in case:**

```
.karussell {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  color: #00A7E0;
  padding: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

#next {
  right: 0;
}
#prev {
  left: 0;
}
.arrow:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00A7E0;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
.karu {
    max-width: 75%;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0.4}
    to {opacity: 1}
}
@media (max-width:767px){.karu{max-width: 95%;}}
```

I made a fiddle to try to illustrate (had to paste the js into the html tab to gt it to work for some reason): [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1jtxcd6/14/)

Comment: Explain what you mean by, "How do I get the Prev/Next buttons to affect the caption as well as the image." As it stands this is very vague.

Comment: `(had to paste the js into the html tab to gt it to work for some reason)` [Here's why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTVqU.png)

Comment: I mean that, when I click the Prev/Next button, I would like both the image AND the caption underneath to change at the same time. So that a specific caption corresponds to a specific image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you just need to use the .innerHTML() feature and do exactly what you already have. Either create a eelmine2() function (or something like that) and call it again, grabbing the content from kiri[] or instead just return the p and use it in two places:

```
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = eelmine();
    document.querySelector('#esikiri').innerHTML = eelmine2();
});
function eelmine2(){
    if (p === 0){
        p = kiri.length;
    }
    p = p - 1;
    return kiri[p];

}
```

or

```
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    var change = eelmine();
    document.querySelector('#karussell img').src = esileht[change];
    document.querySelector('#esikiri').innerHTML = kiri[change];
});
function eelmine(){
    if (p === 0){
        p = kiri.length;
    }
    p = p - 1;
    return p;
}
```

This assumes your code is using the same global vars inside public functions that you have set up in your Fiddle. You should fix that to have variables passed into the functions before going live with all of this, but I'm not addressing that any further here.